# How do I apply Redux concept in a Dart app?

Tags: javascript, redux, dart

I like the idea of having a centralized store in a client app implemented with Redux. It works just fine in the apps when I use JavaScript/TypeScript and [Redux lib](https://github.com/reactjs/redux).

How can I adopt this concept properly in a Dart app? I know there is a [port of Redux](https://github.com/alexeieleusis/greencat) to Dart and even [an example](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-react-counter-example) of the similar approach without libraries. Though, knowing Dart has some nice unique stuff like streams, I wonder if I can not only pull an existing solution into Dart ecosystem but probably have a better solution that works in a similar way as Redux for JS?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it depends on what you're hoping to achieve with Redux. If you're looking for the whole package (stores, actions, reducers) then Alexei's [greencat](https://github.com/alexeieleusis/greencat) (the port of Redux + Thunk that you've mentioned) is the best way.

If you're looking for predictability through immutability, Dart gives you everything from [`const` and `final`](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#final-and-const) to [`@immutable`](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/meta/1.0.5/meta/immutable-constant.html). For true value types, use David's [`package:built_value`](https://github.com/google/built_value.dart).

If you're looking to Redux for stateful hot reload + rewind, Dart+Flutter gives this to you for free ([see video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iPlPk43RbpA)).

I'm sure there's more that Redux is useful for, though.